# Android studio 3.4 layout editor doesn't allow to manipulate elements in the designer for the ConstraintLayout

Tags: android-studio, android-constraintlayout, graphical-layout-editor

I'm trying to create a layout for my app's activity. I've created the empty activity in my android studio project. The problem is that every time I try to add any UI elements by dragging them onto the activity, they are moved to the top-left corner and resized to zero height and width. After that it is not possible to manipulate them in any meaningful way. What am I missing?

Here is the link to a short gif, showing the problem (I am not allowed to post images here directly) - [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqJXV.jpg)

I'm using android studio 3.4, I've tried different types of UI elements, tried restarting the android studio.

Comment: Strange problem. Try invalidating caches and restarting (File->Invalidate Caches/Restart).

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your android studio and add this to your Gradle:

```
 implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

May constraint layout not implemented on your project.